# Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale)

Tags: cpanel

I uploaded a laravel project on the CPanel and I got this error

Declaration of Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface::setLocale($locale) must be compatible with Symfony\Contracts\Translation\LocaleAwareInterface::setLocale(string $locale)

the project works fine on the localhost, my problem is in the CPanel.

the version of my laravel project is 5.8.36

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you ran composer update with a different PHP version than the one that is used to execute the application.

Solution is to do following:-

in `Symfony/translation-contracts/composer.json` edit

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2.9"
},
```

to

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3"
},
```

then add `symfony/translation-contracts: "^1.1.6"` to `project/composer.json` after that run composer update it should work :)